# wp_remote instead of file_get_contents on non json

Tags: wp-remote-get, wp-remote-request

I have searched this website and although there are a lot of threads regarding the wp_remote functions but none are what I am asking and would like to know if its possible.

I am wanting to scrape a website and get a specific div#id and grab its elements within that section.

I can do this using the following php commands:

```
$data=file_get_contents("http://xxxxx.com/xx/xxx/$name");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query("//div[@id='tab1']/table/tbody/tr/td");
```

Then simply getting the information by using the following:

```
$result->item(14)->nodeValue;
```

Is this possible using only wordpress functions rather than using things outside WordPress.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hell yeah it is - check out [the HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) for more information:

```
$http = wp_remote_get( 'http://example.com' );
$data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $http );

// Carry on coding
```